# Is there any way I can pass dynamic data to a component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to pass data that is dynamic to a child component. But I always get the data as undefined in the child component. Below is what I am doing.

ParentComponent.ts

```
results: any[];
ngOnInit() {
this.http.get('url').subscribe(data => this.results = data);
}
```

ParentComponent.html

```
<app-childComponent [dataNeeded]=results></app-childComponent>
```

ChildComponent.ts

```
@Input('dataNeeded') dataNeeded: any[];
ngOnInit() {
 console.log(dataNeeded); //Always undefiend
}
```

So as expected, it doesn't wait for the asynchronous call and returns me undefined. How do i pass the dynamic data to the component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the UI thread will render the child component before the subscribe from the observable finished.

you need to do it like this:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
ngOnInit() {
   this.http.get('url').subscribe(data => { 
     this.results = data;
     this.ref.markForCheck();
   });
}
```

and in the HTML you have to test the value first.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="results != null">
    <app-childComponent [dataNeeded]=results></app-childComponent>
</ng-container>
```

A little description, the [`.markForCheck()`](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#members) will refresh the result after the subscribe and will inform all the components which are using this "value" to update its value, including the ng-container. The container would allow rendering the child component now, which will guarantee that the results are not null when the child will be going through its life cycle.

Answer (score 5):

You might try [OnChanges](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) lifecycle hook method.

In your case, you would need to add it to your child component like so:

```
ngOnChanges(changes) {
  if (changes['dataNeeded'] && this.dataNeeded) {
    console.log(this.dataNeeded);
  }
}
```

**PS** Also I just noticed the wrong syntax in your `ChildComponent.ts`, it is missing `this`:

```
ngOnInit() {
 console.log(this.dataNeeded);
}
```

Comment: It worked for me. I need to show detail records on selecting master record.

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that your service gets `data` successfully so this will work :

in the html of your parent component add the quotes  :

```
<app-childComponent [dataNeeded]="results"></app-childComponent>
```

in your child component , you will check changes of your `Input`using the OnCh:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {   
   for (let propName in changes) {
      // when your @Input value is changed  
      if(propName === "dataNeeded"){
          console.log(dataNeeded);
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this would help :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the Observable with the async pipe.
If you want to console-log that value use a setter.
The async pipe will also take care about unsubscribing.

```
results: Observable<any[]>;
ngOnInit() {
  this.results = this.http.get('url');
}
```

In the HTML

```
<app-childComponent [dataNeeded]="results | async"></app-childComponent>
```

And in your child component

```
@Input('dataNeeded') 
set dataNeeded(val: any[]) {
  console.log(val);
}
```