# Passing async object from a callback from a component to another component when routing in angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angularfire2, angular-components

I have a component "CompA" which has a function named getDocID(), that takes a value from the template on a mouse click and then gets an object asynchronously after doing some query in the firebase with that value.

The problem is, I need to pass this object to another component "CompB" on routing.

This is how my code is looking like right now:

**Template:**

```
 <a (click)="getDocID(doc.docID)">Edit this Document</a>
```

**Component:**

```
getDocID(docID){
  this._docEditService.getSingleDoc(docID, singleDoc => {

    //here will come the async singleDoc object which I need to pass to the edit-doc route

  });
  this._router.navigate(['edit-doc']);
}
```

**Service:**

```
    getSingleDoc(docID, callback) {
    this.userSingleDoc = this.af.database.list('docs', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'docID',
        equalTo: docID
      }
    });

    this.userSingleDoc.forEach(element => {
      for (var el in element) {
        var x = element[el];

        var singleDoc = {
          docID: x['$key'],
          docTitle: x.docTitle,
          docDescription: x.docDescription,
          timestamp: x.timestamp,
        }
        callback(singleDoc)
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried passing an object to another component using service? It's a common pattern that you use service for communication between components. [See the answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44865817/2327713)

Comment: I have tried that. But since the object creation is async, the Another Component (Comp B) loads before the object is there, resulting in undefined values. I have tried calling the object from the service in the Constructor, in ngOnInit, and ngAfterViewInit. No luck till now.

Comment: That's expected because by the time component is mounted the data is not there yet. To achieve this you need **ngOnChanges** lifecycle hook. See my answer here and let me know if it's helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47695003/2327713

Comment: use a service, navigate to other component after setting the object in the service.